# Does the voltage always drop when adding a load?

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

Can we say -across the board- that if you add a load, the voltage will always drop? In this case, I thought, when you consider a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), it is the case that the voltage drops by adding a load. Hence, I assume you will always have a voltage divider of some kind, right?

My main goal is to grasp a general concept/mechanism but I presume, there are voltage-stabilizing circuits to counteract this.

Comment: In the case where a source has a substantial (meaningful) output impedance, then yes... adding a load will drop the voltage. The goal of a voltage regulator is to not have a meaningful output impedance so that adding a load (up to some specified limit) doesn't affect the voltage "much."

Answer (score 3):

> *Does the voltage always drop when adding a load?*

Consider a compound wound DC generator. Depending how you wire the field windings you can get: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://phoneswrite.weebly.com/blog/load-characteristics-of-dc-series-generator-for-california-college-students).

> *Can we say -across the board- that if you add a load, the voltage will
> always drop?*

No we can't.

Comment: Thanks, but this quite a special case, or?

Comment: @Ben - you used the words "across the board" and I took that to mean "under any circumstances". As it happens, pretty much all voltage regulators have an unwanted but inevitable small output impedance that will "drop voltage" with load current AND, all voltage regulation circuits that are effective will attempt to "over-produce" a voltage to compensate for that "voltage drop". So, whatever way you look at it, somewhere, inside a voltage regulation circuit (that attempts to keep the output voltage constant), there will be a node in that circuit that makes a slightly bigger voltage.

Comment: sure, got it, but seeing it may be more physically (?) and not across dozens or more circuits or the like, it would always drop with a load?

Comment: There are other special cases - power supplies with Kelvin terminals for remote sensing for one more example. Add load and you'll see an increase in voltage at the PSU terminals.

Comment: @Ben, I've made my answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

If a source has a real positive output resistor (as many do), then yes, its output voltage will drop as you load it.

Many sources strive to emulate a zero output resistance, to make an ideal voltage regulator, whose voltage is unchanged when you draw current. It's the 'load regulation' line in regulator specifications, the smaller the number the better.

It's quite easy to configure an opamp and a few resistors into a source with a negative output resistance, whose output will now rise when you draw current from it.